# What medical specialty works with patients experiencing permanent loss of taste?

Tags: taste, tongue

What medical professional specializes in the diagnostic evaluation of and treatment of permanent taste loss?

Answer (score 3):

The US National Institutes of Health [notes](https://www.nidcd.nih.gov/health/taste-disorders):

> Both taste and smell disorders are diagnosed by an otolaryngologist (sometimes called an ENT), a doctor of the ear, nose, throat, head, and neck. An otolaryngologist can determine the extent of your taste disorder by measuring the lowest concentration of a taste quality that you can detect or recognize.